Flutter app shows blank screen after first run
I'm trying to run my flutter app, it runs perfectly fine on first run. But when app is closed and opened again, it shows kind of blank screen. Here's the video. the app I am showing this is starter flutter app and i can reproduce it.
i'm pasting my flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.1, on Fedora Linux 40 (Workstation Edition) 6.10.4-200.fc40.x86_64, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 3.24.1 on channel stable at /home/berserkdhanraj/dev/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 5874a72aa4 (12 days ago), 2024-08-20 16:46:00 -0500
    • Engine revision c9b9d5780d
    • Dart version 3.5.1
    • DevTools version 2.37.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /home/berserkdhanraj/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
    • Java binary at: /home/berserkdhanraj/dev/android-studio/jbr/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 18.1.6 (Fedora 18.1.6-3.fc40)
    • cmake version 3.28.2
    • ninja version 1.12.1
    • pkg-config version 2.1.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
    • Android Studio at /home/berserkdhanraj/dev/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 81.0.2
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.92.1)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.94.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64 • Android 14 (API 34) (emulator)
    • Linux (desktop)              • linux         • linux-x64   • Fedora Linux 40 (Workstation Edition) 6.10.4-200.fc40.x86_64

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.


can you show us the Main() function?

Share your code.

It is same starter code when flutter create is executed without any modifications. Is there still a need for me to post code?
